# Jupyter home page not responding

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a brand new Macbook with Monterey. I've set up jupyter in an environment, and last week everything was working fine. This week, I did the following:

```
conda activate chb
jupyter-notebook
```

That gives me the following output (which looks normal to me):

```
[I 09:41:15.985 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/em/Desktop/euv
[I 09:41:15.986 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.8 is running at:
[I 09:41:15.986 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7b5abfb16b32434c89147e191d08fd1e841ce69a11552c09
[I 09:41:15.986 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7b5abfb16b32434c89147e191d08fd1e841ce69a11552c09
[I 09:41:15.986 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:41:16.030 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/em/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-2749-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7b5abfb16b32434c89147e191d08fd1e841ce69a11552c09
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7b5abfb16b32434c89147e191d08fd1e841ce69a11552c09
```

This opens the home page in my browser, as it should, but the page isn't loading my notebooks and it doesn't respond. If left alone, the page crashes after a minute. Nothing had changed or updated since last week, either on the laptop or in the environment (although I did run `conda update jupyter` to see if that would fix it, once the problem presented itself). I've tried multiple browsers, it does the same thing on all of them. Has anyone else had this happen? I'd appreciate any advice; thanks!

Comment: Post us the console output after you invoke `jupyter-notebook`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out the problem and hope this will help other newbies like me: **the notebook server home page opens in whatever folder you're currently in, not your home directory.** The folder in question had thousands of files in it, which made it hang, and wasn't my home directory as I expected. `cd`ing over to my actual home directory loaded everything just fine.